When did the sectors in West Berlin cease to exist?
So, as far as I understand:

Berlin used to be split not just into two (East and West), but within the west there were 3 sectors controlled by the French, the British and the Americans. Some remnants of this can still be seen, with Checkpoint Charlie still standing as a tourist attraction and stating it the "American Sector".
This split within West Berlin was not very pronounced (at least in later days of West Berlin, I don't know about earlier days).
The "proper" occupation of (what was later known as) West Germany ended in 1949 with the formation of West Germany.
However, seemingly these sectors in West Berlin, at least symbolically, lasted quite a bit further. Wikipedia states the map below represents 1987. Checkpoint Charlie was used at least until the wall fell, and at that point it still said "American Sector" (and says so to this day), I'm not very familiar with the other crossing points.


(Uploaded by Paasikivi to Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0 International)
So, when did this whole sector thing in West Berlin properly end? Was there any legal basis to it? I find much more resources online talking about the unification of east and west, presumably because that's the more impactful event.

Beggars can't be choosers, but if anyone wants to talk about the practical effects of the sectors within west berlin, the events between fall of wall, the treaty on the withdrawal of the 4 forces, and and the troops later withdrawing that'd make for a very complete I think.

The way I always understood it was that security of the former Nazi capital was put quasi-equally into the hands of the major Western allies. So they each got their own quarter of the city. "They" being the UN Security Council, minus China who had no dog in this particular fight. Of course the way it shook out was that all but one of those countries was a western democracy, so long-term it became their "West" Berlin vs. the other country's "East" Berlin.

I think West Berlin: Legal Status will answer most of your question. From 1971 until German reunification in 1990 the Four Power Agreement on Berlin was the legal framework.

You have to distinguish between the civil administration and the occupation powers. In 1948 the cooperation between the 4 powers ended and the civil administration split between the existing Magistrat and the Senat of Berlin. Durrng the time of the Berlin blockade (that started on 24. Juni 1948-06-24 and ended on the 1949-05-12), the signs of entering/leaving the western sectors (to each other) disappeared.

@T.E.D. The 'UN Security Council' had absolutely nothing to do with the (initially 3) occupation zones of Germany and the sectors in Berlin. France was added during the Potsdam Conference in July/August 1945. The result of the Berlin blockade was that the German city adminitration (Senat of Berlin) and the western powers became more like partners (even though, formaly, the occupation status remained until 1990).

@MarkJohnson - The UN itself was the official name of the allied organization during the war. The creation of the Security Council was first discussed in 1942, and it was agreed to add France to it at Duraburton Oaks in 1944. The agreement to split Berlin 4 ways among the 4 European UNSC members came from Yalta in February 1945.

@T.E.D. The initial decision to divide Berlin into sectors was made around the 12th of September 1944 by the European Advisory Commission (EAC). As stated, this had nothing to do with the UN.

See: world war two - How and why was the boundary between West and East Berlin decided to be where it was? - History Stack Exchange

@MarkJohnson - Again, The United Nations was the formal name of the alliance between the USA, England, and USSR, and China (and then anyone else they could get to sign on) during the war. Here's a UN War Propaganda poster from 1943. So yes, any multi-party agreement amongst those allies had everything to do with the UN.

[Convert to comment, if the moderators dictate...I know it is not directly responding, but seems additive.] Tangential to your question, one thing many people do not know, is that AUSTRIA was also divided into four zones. As was the city of Vienna. This ended in 1955, with the neutrality proclamation/treaty with the occupying powers, that succeeded in removing the Soviets (and the Western Allies) from the country. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied-occupied_Austria


So, when did this whole sector thing in West Berlin properly end?

On the 15 March 1991, when the ratification process of the Two Plus Four Agreement was compleated.
Between the German reunification (1990-10-03) and the final ratification the allied rights were suspended.

Was there any legal basis to it?

Article 7 of the  Two Plus Four Agreement:

ARTICLE 7
(1) The French Republic, the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America hereby terminate their rights and responsibilities relating to Berlin and to Germany as a whole. As a result, the corresponding, related quadripartite agreements, decisions and practices are terminated and all related Four Power institutions are dissolved.
(2) The united Germany shall have accordingly full sovereignty over its internal and external affairs.



Declaration suspending the Operation of Quadripartite Rights and Responsibilities
The Governments of the French Republic, the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America,
Represented by their Ministers for Foreign Affairs meeting at New York on 1 October 1990,
Having regard to the Treaty on the Final Settlement with respect to Germany signed at Moscow on 12 September 1990, which provides for the termination of their rights and responsibilities relating to Berlin and to Germany as a whole,
Declare that the operation of their rights and responsibilities relating to Berlin and to Germany as a whole shall be suspended upon the unification of Germany, pending the entry into force of the Treaty on the Final Settlement with respect to Germany. As a result, the operation of the corresponding, related quadripartite agreements, decisions and practices and all related Four Power institutions shall likewise be suspended upon the unification of Germany.
The Government of the Federal Republic of Germany, represented by its Minister of Foreign Affairs, and the Government of the German Democratic Republic, represented by its Minister for Education and Science, take note of this declaration.



This split within West Berlin was not very pronounced

In 1948 the cooperation between the 4 powers ended and the civil administration split between the existing Magistrat (then only the east sector) and the Senat of Berlin (the western sectors).



1946
1947









During the time of the Berlin blockade (that started on 1948-06-24 and ended on the 1949-05-12), the signs of entering/leaving the western sectors (to each other) simply disappeared.
For the average person in western Berlin, there was simply no reason for anyone to know in which western sector they were in.
Allied supervision effected mainly the civil administration and police.

The situation when crossing between the eastern and westers sectors was different. For many different reasons, it was important to know that you were crossing over.
The 1959/60 photos, from Allan Hailstone, show that one year before the wall was built, these signs were still in place.



1960-07-31Potsdamer Platz
Friedrichstraße/ZimmerstraßeCheckpoint Charlie









Note: The 1960 photo of Friedrichstraße/Zimmerstraße is one of the very few ones showing the area of the later east German checkpoint before the wall was built (1961-08-13).



1961-10-27
1963










Sources:

Treaty on the Final Settlement with Respect to Germany - Wikipedia

also known as the Two Plus Four Agreement


Allan Hailstone

Berlin in the Cold War, 1959-1966 (Allan Hailstone, Amberley Publishing, October 2017)
Berlin, 1959 and 1960 | Flickr
Berlin, 1962, 1964, 1966 | Flickr


How and why was the boundary between West and East Berlin decided to be where it was? - History Stack Exchange


"Allied supervision effected mainly the civil administration and police." - Was that purely nominal (e.g. pro forma rubber stamping), or were there practical effects of the supervision? And if the latter, were the consequences still sector-based, or did it in practice operate on a joint basis?

@R.M. Laws were checked to insure that they didn't go against their interests and would be done centraly. For the police, which are organized into districts, were always contained within a sector. Unannounced checks were done multiple times a year to insure that all weapons and munitions were accounted for. This was done then per sector. Any interaction with Allied personal (including Soviet) required the calling the responsible Allied authority depending where the event happend and they would take over. From the 20 years I served as a police reserve officer, that was pretty much everything.

Cute detail: the US Army Military Police driving around in a Ford Taunus P3.

The American sector and the "Western sectors" (plural) are explicitely mentioned in the Four Powers Agreement on Berlin of 1971, or at least in this German translation.
I believe that for most matters, there was no difference between the Western sectors by that time, but it may still have mattered for members of the French, British and American militaries?
According to this German wikipedia article, the sectors existed until 1990. It also gives some examples of how the Western Allies tried to assert that East Berlin was just another sector, while East Germany tried to erode that status.
